# Is it safe to keep my laptop plugged in all the time?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, charging

I am using  battery health software which came factory installed with my laptop which limits your charging percentage to 79% and no matter how much I charge it, it will not go above it. I did this to reduce the amount of battery cycles.

Can anyone tell me that after using this software is it safe for the battery to be plugged in all the time?

Will plugging the laptop all day after limiting charging percentage to 80% not damage my laptop?

Comment: Why are you using that software if it is either incorrect or actually hurting your system, or do you intend for this? I cannot tell from your question what the intent or outcome actually was.

Comment: I intentionally used the software to do so , i wanted to know , if the software is helping me to keep my battery percentage at 79 percent all the time no matter how much i charge so is it ok to keep my machine plugged in all the time if it does not get ahead of the 80 percent threshold ? and it is a 4 month old machine

Comment: What makes you think a modern laptop needs to keep its battery set to less than 80 percent charge to extend its life? Why are you concerned about extending the batter life of a laptop that is only 4 months old?

Comment: @music2myear i want to keep my laptop plugged in most of the time so i was thinking that if i limit it to around 80 percent and keep it plugged in then it will not damage the battery even is it so ?

Comment: Make and model of laptop?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question is valid and reasonable and I will endeavor to answer them:

1. With the manufacturer's battery threshold software installed and enabled, the common value to stop charging at is 80%. Your laptop does this and my two Lenovo laptops do this.
2. **Is it safe to do this?** Yes it is safe. My second laptop (Lenovo X230) is 8 years old and the battery is the second one (4 years old) and it has been plugged in for about 6 months (pandemic) non-stop. No damage whatever. Battery capacity is half of new because of age.
3. **Will it be damaged?** Similar to number 2. No, it will not be damaged. My other machine (Lenovo X1 Carbon) is 4 years old  and the second battery is 18 months old. It is now plugged in all the time (some power down / up in the early part of the pandemic). Battery capacity is high (much newer battery).

Reduction in battery capacity when left plugged in to 80% is more a function of age (all batteries age and wear out) than from using battery threshold software.

I believe what you are doing is safe and reasonable.

Comment: While I think this question is too vague and has issues I believe this answer is really the best one to address the issues here. It’s reasonable and addresses the issues without resorting to “panic” implications about manufacturers trying to screw over consumers with batteries that wear out excessively. Especially this: “Reduction in battery capacity when left plugged in to 80% is more a function of age (all batteries age and wear out) than from using battery threshold software.”

Comment: Each manufacturer (Dell, HP, etc...) has software to do this... https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-11/how-to-limit-battery-charge-to-a-certain-percentage-in-windows-11-10/

Answer (score -1):

Having battery's plugged in all the time will deplete it but each time you charge can also deplete it
you could use the manufacturer's software to prevent it from charging above a certain percentage but if you are going to keep it plugged in 24/7 disconnect the battery so the charger cable will only power the PC and not deplete the battery if you need to move the laptop plug the battery back in and you should be able to move around
but you can use the manufacturer's software or software found online to control the charging.

Comment: I intentionally used the software to do so , i wanted to know , if the software is helping me to keep my battery percentage at 79 percent all the time no matter how much i charge so is it ok to keep my machine plugged in all the time if it does not get ahead of the 80 percent threshold ? and it is a 4 month old machine

Comment: Repeatedly cycling *any* battery chemistry, whether Li-ion, Pb-acid, NiMH or other, eventually damages the battery, first reducing the amount of charge it can retain and finally causing dendrite growth and internal short circuits. The "answer" is misinformation.

Comment: If you are using the Battery software from the Manufacturer to set the Battery threshold to limit charge between 70 and 80%, you can use that reliably and leave your computer plugged in. I use Lenovo Computers and Lenovo Vantage and set the maximum charge to 80%. You should not harm a good battery this way, and I have not harmed my X1 battery (16 months on second battery) or my X230 (4 years on second battery). Whatever you do a modern battery has a lifespan of about 5 years plus or minus.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik cant understand can you put it in a more simple way, the software cam preloaded from the brand and i thought to give it a try

Comment: @John yes it is from the manufacturer's app which came preloaded, so basically you are saying i can limit the battery to 80 percent and use it plugged in most of the time without damaging the battery right ?

Comment: If the manufacturer supplied the software it should work fine using a limit of of 80% charge. I am doing this myself with Lenovo Vantage

Comment: Thanks for the new Information I will Edit the post now to make it more accurate

Comment: Maybe 10 years ago this advice would be valid, but unless you know what model laptop the original poster is using this answer is just “truthy.” It is bad advice because it implies setting magical limits on some vague software will somehow save battery life.

Answer (score -1):

#### Using that battery charge limiter is appropriate in your scenario.

As far as I know, only some models of Lenovo and Dell laptops have battery charge limiter functionality built into their motherboards. The firmware present there is exactly for the purpose of saving the battery from wearing down during periods when the laptop is kept plugged in or in days if you do not need the full lifetime of the battery.

In battery care articles around the Internet you can read that it is recommended to keep the battery charged between **80% and 30%** of its capacity. Keeping the battery charged at the maximum of 80% is much better than at the 100% for its life span.

Older Lenovo models do not have battery levels adjustable, they offer only two charging ceilings: 100% and 60%. And the latter one does almost wonders: I have 8 years-old battery  with still about half of usable capacity. Such a result won't be possible if kept at 100%. Obviously they knew what they were doing when fixing upper charge limit at 60%. So for keeping your laptop plugged in permanently, you can follow that old Lenovo idea and lower your upper limit from 80% to 60% for even better handling of the battery. (And set lower limit somewhere to 50%.)